# CSS style doesn't apply to container div

Tags: css, html, styles, containers

CSS style works (as far as I can see) for all elements except the container div.
I can't get it to work, I have tried everything. It should have width and height and a black background color. This is the code that doesn't apply :

```
#container {
    width: 588px;
    height: 617px;
    background-color:#000;
    margin: auto;    
}
```

The code seems right. Both CSS and HTML have passed the w3c validators.

Please help, I'm clueless. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

right now, looking at the html of your page, you have set the container tag as a class. You need to set it either as a div id, or change it to a class in the css.

so in the code above, simply change the # to a . (period) in front of container

```
.container {   /* replaced # with a period */
    width: 588px;
    height: 617px;
    background-color:#000;
    margin: auto;    
}
```

Comment: No problem. Happens to all of us.

Comment: @user1880779 Please remember to choose an answer! :)

Comment: don't worry, i wont forget you :) and you don't forget to upvote stupid questions like mine :P

Answer (score 2):

you container is a `class` instead of an `id`